# Separating 'Wsdl service reference' into 'Contracts\ Model' Project and 'Services' project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

When adding a WSDL service reference ( in visual studio) id like to separate the generated code into:

1. the objects ( like response\ request objects and depending model classes) should go into a 'Model\Contracts' project shared by other projects.
2. the operation definitions and calling classes should go into something like a 'service' project not shared by many projects.

Tying to add the classes 'as link' doesn't work as these classes aren't really generated into real files - and then there will also be namespace issues.

any ideas ?

thanks